# Share POWER BI report outside organization and without PowerBI installed

Tags: powerbi

I work at a consulting firm and would love to share some dashboards to clients. But they usually don't have a PowerBI app and they are all form outside the organization. Is there a quick way to share it to them? I don't think I can develop the website just for them in 2 days.

Thank you

Comment: This is almost certainly off topic for StackOverflow.  If you are having a specific problem with (e.g.: report authoring with DAX, or PowerBI Embedded API, etc...), the question should be edited to address that specific issue.  If the question remains "how can I share outside the organization," then https://superuser.com/ is your best bet.

Comment: Ignoring that, PowerBI embedded will let you do that - but you have write a website or something to embed it in (starts at $250/mo).  PowerBI Premium Workspaces will let you do it without development, but that starts at $60k/y.  You can also assign guests paid PowerBI Pro licenses ($10/mo/u) per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have several options,

1. You can create power bi dashboard from your desktop app and publish in to your tenant. you can share dashboard with clients who have power bi pro or premium licence. If they have licence they can do same things you can do in your tenant.
2. Ant if you want to send just snapshot of dashboard you can just share or download
   pdf/powerpoint slide and share. but stakeholders cant do any adjustment in that file since its snapshot kind a thing.